# What is the most scalable/secure way to handle refresh tokens in a JWT authentication setup?

Tags: java, node.js, authentication, redis, jwt

I am building my own authentication microservice and although I have the main setup in place (generating access tokens etc.), I am a bit lost when it comes to refresh tokens.

I feel there are a lot of different way to handle this.

- You can either store them in Redis or in the database.
- You can use a whitelist or a blacklist them

Right now, my idea is to add another database table that links a valid refresh token to a user entity. When a user hits the logout endpoint, the refresh token gets destroyed.

I was wondering if this was a good solution and otherwise, if there are other possible solutions to consider. I have seen a number of articles when googling but they stem from anywhere between 2015 and 2019, and they all have different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with refresh tokens is not so much where or how you store them on the server side, as well if and how you store them on the client side.

It all depends on whether you can trust your client (software using the token) to keep secrets. You only want to issue refresh tokens to a client you can trust to keep these tokens secure. Typically, this means only issue refresh tokens to [confidential clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1), i.e. web applications that run on a web server. These clients can also have their own (client) credentials to authenticate themselves with when using the refresh token.

For public (non-confidential) clients, like Single Page Applications, some OAuth2 libraries use an hidden IFRAME and a cookie session with the authorization server to issue new access tokens.

So, the answer to your question depends on what kind of clients you will be using.